# Get Object i.attribute Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, vue.js

I have been trying but unable to succeed. How do I access the value `i.MoveTo` dynamically so I can perform logic on *that exact value*?

I have an array of objects like the below which have an `x` and `y` value but their "names" are `i.MoveTo`  and `i.LineTo` respectively.

I need to perform logic on these objects based on the objects "name" or whatever category the value `i.MoveTo` falls into.

[image]

Some of the things I have tried :

- `item.constructor.name`
- `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(item)`
- `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(item))`

Comment: it's an object, not string.

Comment: I know it is an object as I state in the question when I say I have an array of objects like that. I however need the value i.MoveTo from that object as a string so I can perform logic with that String.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to understand the concept of [JavaScript Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects). The object which you are trying to access is/are an instance of a specific class. So, you can use [instanceOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) operator to check the name.

Here is an example from the documentation

```
function Car(make, model, year) {
  this.make = make;
  this.model = model;
  this.year = year;
}
var auto = new Car('Honda', 'Accord', 1998);

console.log(auto instanceof Car);
// expected output: true
```

So, now you can check your object like in the example.

```
if(i instanceof MoveTo){
//Do your logic
}
```